# What kind of nonstick coating is this?

Tags: baking, equipment

I recently bought [a Good Cook brand sheet cake pan,](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Good-Cook-13-Inch-x-9-Inch-Bake-Roast-Pan/48283547?sourceid=csebr038c0f9507e5934fbd87294c52fba0760b&wmlspartner=bizratecom&affcmpid=2307260423&tmode=0000&veh=cse&szredirectid=14670935659170092793110080301008005) not realizing that it was nonstick. I'm was wondering what kind of nonstick coating it had, since the only coatings I know of are ceramic and teflon, and I usually expect to see a darker color on teflon pans.

[image: A light gray sheet cake pan]

What kind of nonstick coating does this pan have?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply teflon. It can be colored in any color, but the lighter colors will darken with overheating, so it is convenient to coat a pan in an "overheated" color from the beginning. The manufacturer here chose to use a different color.

Comment: That's really interesting, but I guess it explains why teflon is almost always black. Do you have any source that suggests that it's used in this type of pan, or are you inferring?

Answer (score 2):

The "brand" seems remarkably shy - no website could be found for them, and no vendor admits what the non-stick coating actually is in this case.

It appears (via internet picture) visually similar to the coating on "Bakers Secret" which is a silicone coating on steel. That works for a while, longer if you are careful to wash it promptly. But without a vendor site admitting to the actual construction, there's no way to tell what it is.